# Processing unicode characters in command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, unicode-string

I have a project on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Debian-based Linux OS) where I have to pass command-line parameters to a Python 3 program. I need to be able to pass a unicode string.

I am not sure how exactly this should be set up. It is clear that there are several conversions the command line string is going through before the data is passed to Python.

Let's start with the fact that I can see the Unicode characters correctly, when I press the required keystrokes in the terminal session. Here is some test code:

```
$ echo "ā" > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
ā
$ hexdump test.txt 
0000000 81c4 000a                              
0000003
```

That 0x81c4 word, or two-byte sequence 0xc4+0x81 is "ā" encoded to UTF-8.

Now, if I try to pass the same character to Python, I get a two-character string with weird character codes:

```
import sys
param = sys.argv[1]
print([hex(ord(char)) for char in param])

$ python test.py ā
['0xdcc4', '0xdc81']
```

One can notice that the character codes are related to the 0xc4+0x81 byte sequence, but here each byte is added 0xdc00.

If I go in the interactive console, the unicode character manipulation is just the same as with ordinary characters:

```
>>> txt = 'ā'
>>> len(txt)
1
>>> hex(ord(txt[0]))
'0x101'
```

0x101 is a correct code point for the character "ā".

So, my question is, how can I reliably convert from the two-character `['0xdcc4', '0xdc81']` string to the one-character string "ā", that would work on all platforms?

Comment: Don't know about working on all platforms but perhaps you can give this a try: `bytes([int(s[4:], 16) for s in ['0xdcc4', '0xdc81']]).decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly at which point this happens, but the command line parameters apparently are expected to contain only ASCII characters, and to decode the byte array to a string, [bytes.decode(encoding, errors)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) is used:

```
param = b'\xc4\x81'.decode('ASCII', 'surrogateescape')
print(param == '\udcc4\udc81') # True
```

When the decoder stumbles upon a non-ASCII character, it processes the decoding according to the selected error handler. In this case, `surrogateescape` error handler replaces byte with individual surrogate code ranging from U+DC80 to U+DCFF.

So, the way to fix this is to encode the incorrectly decoded string back to byte array, using the same `surrogateescape` error handler, and then decode it as `utf-8`:

```
import sys
param = sys.argv[1]
param_unicode = param.encode('ASCII', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8')
print(param_unicode)

$ python test.py ā
ā
```

It should be verified, though, if the command line parameters really are always decoded using the ASCII encoding. Perhaps it is different on different platforms and is configurable.